# [rospack] Error: stack/package stage_ros not found; in ROS Fuerte, Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: simulation, simulator-stage, stage, stageros, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all.
I am very new to ROS and Ubuntu. I am working under Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS Fuerte. I was trying to make teleop_base tutorial with stage (Simulating one robot). After the teleop_base installation I tried to run:

$ rosrun stage_ros stageros $(rospack find stage_ros)/world/willow-erratic.world

And I have got this error:

[rospack] Error: stack/package stage_ros not found
[rospack] Error: stack/package stage_ros not found

I was trying to find out how solve it in the internet (I assume, that I need to install stage_ros), but I did not find anything useful. At least anything that I can understand and use (as I am newbie). Please help me!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203466/%5Brospack%5D-error:-stack/package-stage_ros-not-found;-in-ros-fuerte,-ubuntu-12.04/) by [Dio Eraclea](https://answers.ros.org/users/21681/dio-eraclea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Install ros-fuerte-stage

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dio Eraclea](https://answers.ros.org/users/21681/dio-eraclea/) on 2015-02-20**:
By running:

sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-stage

It says that the newest version is already installed on my computer.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-02-20**:
I believe the package is named stage in fuerte, so `rosrun stage stageros` should work.